# How to make text flow to next line up, and hide the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on the display portion of a calculator. I have a div, with two divs, each with text, inside it.

```
<div>
<div>I'm text</div>
<div>I'm text</div>
</div>
```

The user can use buttons to add text to the divs. I want the top div to be a maximum of two lines and vertically-aligned to the bottom. When it exceeds this length, the overflow should be out of the top and hidden. I.e. the overflow should show the bottom part of the excessive text, and hide the top part.

I have searched similar questions relating to hiding images or links and tried their solutions. These generally revolve around using the following properties: position, width, height, bottom, overflow, vertical-align, word-wrap. I've understood most of these, but haven't been able to get them to work. One solution I haven't been able to successfully attempt appears to try and use some combination of the above with an additional nested div.

At this point, I've got the height & width controlled. The top div will only display two lines of text. I also have the overflow working. When it's too long, it is hidden.

The problem is that the bottom is hidden, instead of the top.

This is what it looks like. Notice the twos aren't visible, they're hidden:

[image]

This is what I want. Notice the twos are visible:

[image]

Here's relevant HTML & CSS, and below that is the link to a codepen if you need more information:

HTML (trouble div is #memory):

```
<div id=calculator>

            <div id=displaybox>
                  <div id=memory>
                  0
                  </div>
                  <div id=display>0</div>

            </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#calculator {
      border-style: solid;
      height: 325px;
      width: 260px;
      margin:auto;
      margin-top:10px;
      border-radius:8px;
      background-color: #494949;
      font-family: 'Audiowide';
}

#displaybox {
      border-style:solid;
      border-width:3px;
      width:227.5px;
      margin-left:12px;
      margin-right:auto;
      border-radius: 8px;
      text-align:right;
      margin-top:20px;
      padding-right:12px;
      padding-left:3px;
      font-size:30px;
      background-color:#D4D7A1;
      height: 75px;
}

#memory {
      font-size:15px;
      padding-right:3px;
      line-height: 15px;
      margin-top:5px;
      padding-left:12px;
      color:#767676;
      margin-bottom:-7px;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      height:30px;
      width:207px;
      overflow:hidden;
      vertical-align: top !important;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ethan-vernon/pen/WyQqzM"https://codepen.io/ethan-vernon/pen/WyQqzM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change to the #memory block did it:

Added **display: flex** and **flex-flow: column-reverse**

```
#memory{
     font-size: 15px;
     padding-right: 3px;
     line-height: 15px;
     margin-top: 5px;
     padding-left: 12px;
     color: #767676;
     margin-bottom: -7px;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     height: 30px;
     width: 207px;
     overflow: hidden;
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: column-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not found an answer yet still for CSS/HTML solution. However, I turned to jQuery/JavaScript and have solved my problem by calling the below function after each update to the #memory div.

```
function heightCheck(str) {

      console.log(str.substr(1));
      console.log('memory: ' + $("#memory").height());
      while ($("#memory").height()>30) {
            str=str.substr(1);
            $("#memory").text(str);
            console.log(str);
            console.log($("#memory").height());
      }

}
```